# Can't compile va_arg() call using templated type because of comma in template parameters

Tags: c++, g++, variadic-functions

This line:

```
minimum= va_arg(arguments, Vector<T, dimension_count>);
```

Won't compile because the comma makes the compiler think there's three arguments instead of two. This I figured out several months ago when I first wrote it. My workaround was to simply put the template type inside of a set of parenthesis. This worked in Visual Studio's compiler up until today, when I switched to G++, which refuses to compile because it

> "expected type-specifier before '(' token".

So it appears I'm damned if I do, damned if I don't. Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `typedef` to turn your Vector type into a simpler name with no commas in it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what the type or dimensionality of the incoming Vector's are at compile time, so I can't use one of my simple names like Vector3f.

Comment: @user2345397: So what? Just put `typedef vector<T, dimension_count> theTypeOfTheVector;` before the call to `va_arg`. (Or `using theType=std::vector<T, dimension_count>;`, possibly even more readable.)

Comment: Thanks, both of you, didn't realize I could do that!